# Copy specific text from one file to another

Tags: linux, rhel, regular-expression

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Start find in flight queries
2018-03-05 15:50:02,069:INFO:######################################
Start find completed queries
2018-03-05 15:50:02,070:INFO:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): server060
2018-03-05 15:50:02,083:DEBUG:"GET /queries?json HTTP/1.1" 401 0
2018-03-05 15:50:02,084:INFO:Resetting dropped connection: server060
2018-03-05 15:50:02,095:DEBUG:"GET /queries?json HTTP/1.1" 200 19059
2018-03-05 15:50:02,099:INFO:######################################
Start find in flight queries
```

The date and time **changes** every 5 minutes. I need to copy the **very last** date and time to another file. In this example its 2018-03-05 15:50:02.
Any suggestions are appreciated. I have used a little regex in the past but not good at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`tac`** + **`grep`** solution:

```
tac input.txt | grep -Eo -m1 '^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}' > last_date.txt
```

Comment: excellent! Is there something you used to help you figuring this out so quickly?

Comment: @user3508766, yes, I use my mind )

Comment: haha very good, spasibo bolshoe

Comment: @user3508766, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) without pipes ;)

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '
    /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/
    {var=$1" "$2}
    END{print var}
' file
```